# Will a Flash 9 SWF perform poorly in a Flash 10 player?

Tags: flash

I created a Flash video player a long time ago when Flash 9 still had a sizable market share. Now that nearly everyone has Flash 10 player, I am wondering if I should publish as Flash 10. I don't believe that I'm using any level 10 API calls, because my Flash compiles fine at level 9.

1. Is the performance of the SWF determined by the client's Flash player or my publish version?
2. Will Flash 10's video hardware decoding not kick in if I publish as Flash 9?

Comment: I guess you could publish two separate files, one for Flash 9 and one for Flash 10, and profile them (somehow).

Comment: How would I profile the two SWFs side by side?

Answer (score 0):

If it publishes and runs fine on 9 then you will notice no difference on 10

Comment: Can you explain in detail what happens when a Flash 10 player plays a Flash 9 SWF? Doesn't Flash 10 need to take some backwards compatibility paths that could be not as optimized as the newer paths? And how does the compiler change according to the publish version?

Comment: If you compiled the swf to version 9 then the flash player on the client side will see that and load use version 9 libraries.

Comment: It is always best to use the most current release version of flash player. Flash player is 100% backward compatible to older versions. As far as optimized code I highly doubt an older version would be more optimized then a newer.

Comment: There is a few small exceptions however mostly due to security that was added in version 10. For example FileReference class needs a user interaction to process the browse function